# C# Update column in Excel from file loaded in DataGridView via OpenFileDialog with a value selected from a ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, openfiledialog

I have a small form which has 2 `Buttons` (`Browse` & `updateExcel`), a `ComboBox` (`comboBox1`) and a `DataGridView` (`dataGridView1`)

The first button lets you select an Excel file and then loads in the file to the `DataGridView`:

```
private void Browse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        OpenFileDialog op = new OpenFileDialog();
        op.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
        op.Title = "Browse Excel Files";
        op.CheckFileExists = true;
        op.CheckPathExists = true;
        op.DefaultExt = "xls";
        op.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm;*.csv";
        op.FilterIndex = 2;
        op.RestoreDirectory = true;
        op.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
        op.ShowReadOnly = true;

        if (op.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if (File.Exists(op.FileName))
            {
                string[] Arr = null;
                Arr = op.FileName.Split('.');
                if (Arr.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (Arr[Arr.Length - 1] == "xls")
                        sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" +
                        op.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
                }
                else if (Arr[Arr.Length - 1] == "xlsx")
                {
                    sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + op.FileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';";
                }
            }
            FillData();
        }
    }
```

This also uses the following code:

```
    public string sConnectionString;
    private void FillData()
    {
        if (sConnectionString.Length > 0)
        {
            OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);
            {
                cn.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OleDbDataAdapter Adpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [sheet1$]", cn);
                Adpt.Fill(dt);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            try { }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the file is displayed I have a `ComboBox` (`comboBox1`) which has set static values that can be selected.

What I am trying to to do is on another button (`updateExcel`) this takes the value you have selected in the `ComboBox` and then replaces all values in column C.

Current Usings:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
```

For example:

If my Excel file is:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff
ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll
mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr
```

And I choose `XXX` from the `ComboBox` I would want the output to be:

```
a   b   c   d   e   f
aaa bbb XXX ddd eee fff
ggg hhh XXX jjj kkk lll
mmm nnn XXX ppp qqq rrr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using the following code:

```
    private void updateExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1[2, i].Value = ConsigneeCombo.Text;
        }
    }
```